# Teradata client for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, teradata

i'm kind of begginer in ruby and my question is how to remote a Teradata database using ruby, and for that I found a gem that does the job  but I have no idea how to make it work.

The gem I'm talking about is teradata-cli (0.0.12), and it requires CLIV2 for teradata, a set of callable services to do stuff on teradata databases.

So I couldn't manage to make the gem work because I don't know how to manage dependencies, any hints to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is off-topic for SO as written because it's too broad. We don't know your expertise so we'd have to write a tutorial. Instead, we expect you to have done the research, learned, then tried, and after going through that loop, to ask a question once you're stuck. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 might help you understand the expectations.

Answer (score 1):

The gem `teradata-cli` is outdated and no one maintain it. Alternatively, Teradata REST API offers comprehensive interface to access from any programming language.
https://docs.teradata.com/reader/4fQ6Il0rzVPkL0wmAXt7jA/wK5S_1YbG3KbIYJKfcYytQ